# I want to know what type of invoking do you call below ... Specifically the highlighted phrase "xhr.onload"

Tags: javascript, json, callback, xmlhttprequest

What type of invoking is xhr.onload?

[image]**

I know that we are using a callback function upon event completion but I'm not used to seeing the function invoked without the parantheses like this . Why didn't I need to write **"xhr.onload()"**

```
function loadData(e){
  const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.open('GET','data.json',true);

  xhr.onload=function(){ // this one 

    if(this.status===200){
        console.log(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=`<h1>${this.responseText}</h1>`;
    }
    
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: It is an event handler. You are assigning a new function to the onload function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onload It is just like when you bind event listeners for click, submit, etc.

Comment: It's not an invocation at all, that's why there are no parentheses. Instead, you are assigning a function there, which the XHR code will later call for you. The actual call (which is not in _your_ code, it's in the internal code of the XHR) will have the parentheses but you don't see that here because it's not in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is an event handler. You are assigning a new anonymous function to the onload function which is not set until you set it

Alternative (also without brackets is

```
function xhrLoad() {...}

...

xhr.onload=xhrLoad;
```

or

```
xhr.addEventListener("load",xhrLoad)
```

or again as a so-called anonymous function:

```
xhr.addEventListener("load",function() { ... })
```

If you want to do

```
xhr.onload=somethingWithBrackets()
```

you can, but then the called function needs to return a function because it will be called immediately, but the onload has to be called when the ajax function returns - a callback:

```
function somethingWithBrackets() {
  return function() { .... } // onload NEEDS  function so we return one like this
}
```

Comment: I think he's asking why you don't write `xhr.onload = xhrLoad()`

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a callback function, you don't provide the arguments at that place. The function will be called later by whatever is using the callback, and it will pass arguments to it.

In this case, the function isn't called when you assign to `xhr.onload`. That saves a reference to the function, and the browser will call the function when the AJAX response is received.

If you put `()` after the function, it would call the function before the assignment, not when the `load` event occurs.